# Calling named parameters of a MSSQL stored procedure in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an existing MSSQL Stored procedure that I need to call in my laravel app. I know that I can use advanced wheres in laravel eloquent, but the client expects that I should be calling that Stored procedure.

I need to call the SP as follows

```
exec sp_getDepends @Action= 'smn',@DependencyID = 12345
```

I know that I can use `DB:statement` but I dont know how to pass the named params.

Can you please help me out with this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::select(DB::raw("exec dbo.sp_getDepends :Action, :DependencyID"),
[':Action' => $Action, ':DependencyID' => $DependencyID]);
```

The dbo. may need to be removed, not 100% sure if this is what you 
looking for but I hope it will put you on the right track.

Comment: I am sorry that did not work. This is what was executed - exec sp_getDepends :Action, :DependencyID{":Action":"SI",":DependencyID":"89019"}

Answer (score 0):

I had to find a solution to this, so here it is.

```
DB::select('exec sp_getDepends @Action = ?, @DependencyID = ?', ['smn', '12345'])
```

If you just want to pass a single parameter, which in this case, maybe is DependencyID, you can do that using:

```
DB::select('exec sp_getDepends @DependencyID = ?', ['12345'])
```

You get the general idea.

The question is asking how to call the named parameters of a MSSQL stored procedure in laravel. Which is what I've answered. If you want to use named parameters in laravel, I think it's probably something like:

```
DB::select('exec sp_getDepends @Action = :ActionParam, @DependencyID = :DependencyIDParam'), ['ActionParam' => 'smn', 'DependencyIDParam' => '12345']);
```